# Image Resize - Interpolation with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv, html5-canvas, resize, interpolation

I have an image like the picture below. I need to resize this image.(between x2 and x10)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIpYX.png

When I resized with Canvas's own features, I couldn't get the image I wanted. The image was pixelated.

I used OpenCV's javascript library for this. (To be able to do interpolation)

```
var src = cv.imread(myCanvas);
var dst = new cv.Mat();
var dsize = new cv.Size(this.canvas.width,  this.canvas.height);

cv.resize(src, dst, dsize, 0, 0, cv.INTER_LINEAR);
//cv.resize(src, dst, dsize, 0, 0, cv.INTER_AREA);
//cv.resize(src, dst, dsize, 0, 0, cv.INTER_CUBIC);
//cv.resize(src, dst, dsize, 0, 0, cv.INTER_NEAREST);
//cv.resize(src, dst, dsize, 0, 0, cv.INTER_LANCZOS4);
//cv.resize(src, dst, dsize, 0, 0, cv.INTER_LINEAR_EXACT);
cv.imshow("schemaCanvas", dst);
src.delete(); dst.delete();
```

I tried all the algorithms in OpenCV but here I could not get the exact result I wanted and its speed was slow (40-60 ms) The resizing speed in my application needs to be between about 10 and 20 ms.

Then I wanted to write an algorithm myself, but I could not prevent pixelation, and the image I wanted was not revealed.

I have to get an image like this. Of course quickly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebooI.png

The transition between colors is soft and I need to resize in real time without pixelation. I have tried many different algorithms and libraries. (Pica, OpenCV, Ola, Paper etc. libraries, Hermite, Lanczos etc. algorithms)

It would be great if someone with experience in this field could give an idea about speed or the algorithm it uses.

Comment: This appears to be a "gimme the codes" question, i.e. you appear to be asking for someone to write the entire algorithm for you. That's not what this site is for. Please post the version of the algorithm you currently have, plus any attempt you may have made at creating the gradients you're after, and ask how you can fix your existing code to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Actually, I do not mean "gimme the codes", I mean the discussion and the guidance, but I updated the question.

Comment: You certainly may not have meant that, but that's what it *looked like* you meant. Thank you for clarifying the question - your edit will also have bumped it onto the frontpage and should hopefully get it some more attention. Just don't go editing it every five minutes or you'll get in trouble.